# Callback when embedded Google Calendar has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, google-calendar-api, onload

I am loading an embedded Google calendar the standard way:

```
<iframe id="calendar" src="https://www.google.com/calendar/embed...></iframe>
```

I want to apply some style changes after the load event using jQuery, e.g.:

```
$('iframe#calendar').contents().find('.blahblah').css("display", "none");
```

I presumably need to use an interval loop:

```
var interval_calendar = setInterval(function(){
    if ($('#calendar').SOMETHING) {
        clearInterval(interval_calendar);
        $('iframe#calendar').contents().find('.blahblah').css("display", "none");
    }
} ,200);
```

How can I check that the calendar is loaded? Basically, I need the `SOMETHING`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
        var iframe = $("<iframe>", {
                "id" : "calendar",
                "src" : "https://www.google.com/calendar/embed...",
                "target" : "_top"
        })
        // `iframe` `load` `event`
        .on("load", function (e) {
            $(e.target)
            .contents()
            .find(".blablah")
            .css("display", "none");
            return false
        });
        // $(element).append($(iframe))
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/a3UL5/

Answer (score 1):

You could use `load` to execute a function when your iframe is done loading...

```
$("#calendar").load( function () {
    // do something once the iframe is loaded
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not find any good JavaScript Event solution, but you can use your idea:

```
var interval_calendar = setInterval(function(){
    if ($('#calendarTitle').html()!= "") {
        clearInterval(interval_calendar);
        alert();
    }
} ,200);
```

The `calendarTitle` id is shown on the page only when the whole calendar loaded.

In the other hand I don't know if you can access the calendar attributes, as they are protected. You can only access the iframe content that was loaded from your host. With an `alert()`
 it works, but if you try to access any inside content you will get a `SecurityError` message into console.